# Product of n uniformly distributed RVs

Tags: statistics, products, uniform-distribution

Let $X_j \sim U(a,b)$. What is the PDF of $\prod_{j=1}^n X_j$? I have seen some with $X_j \sim U(0,1)$ but I was wondering what the general form of the solution is for any $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Note that $X_j$~$U[0,1]$ is just a _linear_ transformation of another $Y_j$~$U[a,b]$

Comment: I know that $\log(X_j) \sim \exp(1)$ What I am unclear on is how the bounds change. It has been a while since I have done this.

Comment: The $X_j$ are independent, or may be correlated?

Comment: Assuming a is positive, the bounds become a^n and b^n and the PDF becomes a mess.

Comment: I should have specified. They are all iid.

Comment: One of the specific cases I am looking for is $a=0.1$ and $b=1$. I thought it would be quite complicated in a general form but worth asking.